# Gnome Sort not sorting in python?

Tags: python

When I try to run my code it returns with none.

```
def gnomeSort(lis):
    i = 0
    n = len(lis)
    while i < n:
        if i and lis[i] < lis[i-1]:
            lis[i], lis[i-1] = lis[i-1], lis[i]
            i -= 1
        else:
            i += 1
    return


lis = [1,3,5,20,19,30,2,6,19,23,31,90,44,62,69,21,78,89,64]
print(gnomeSort(lis))
```

When I run this it returns with "None", even though I provided a list to be sorted.

Comment: your return statement is not returning anything, hence `None`, try `return lis`

Comment: You need to put something after your return statement, as currently it is not returning anything

Comment: This implementation sorts *in-place*, meaning you just call it on `lis` and then print `lis`.

Comment: Did you try this simple command to sort your list.

`print sorted(lis)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wrote your function much like the built-in `sort` functions: it sorts the list in place and returns `None`.  Print the sorted list, not the return value.

```
print(lis)
```